# Incorrect Boot Time In `psutil.boot_time()` on windows with Python?

Tags: python, psutil

When running `psutil.boot_time()` for the first time (yesterday) on my windows computer it shows the correct boot time. But when I am running it today it shows yesterday's boot time!

what to do? Am I Doing Something Wrong?

Comment: Did you reboot in between?  Note that closing the lid on your laptop does not constitute rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't booted it again, the boot_time will be the same.